# @input decorator instead of dependency injection service in Angular

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular2-template, angularjs-decorator

As far as I have understood, when there is persistent data from a database or a class with constant values, we should use dependency injection, because we can send a service as a parameter within the constructor of the class that we are going to instantiate. That service doesn't need to be instantiated, neither passed as parameter, since it knows where to get the data from, and the class that is going to use is just going to call it whenever it is instantiated.

But when the information is not persistent neither constant, we should use the @input decorator in the child component and pass the parameter values using the html template of the parent.

For example, let say that we have a matrix

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'app-matrix',
      })
```

And it has rows and columns and rows

```
export class MatrizComponent implements OnInit {
  columnsQuantity:number;
  rowsQuantity:number;
}
```

Lets say that these rows and columns become from a Database or a Constant data class and we use a service to get that data, so that we can extend the class with a constructor that gets a service

```
export class MatrixComponent implements OnInit {
  columnsQuantity:number;
  rowsQuantity:number;
  constructor(private service:MatrixService) { 

  }
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.columnsQuantity = this.service.getColumnsQuantity();
    this.rowsQuantity = this.service.getRowsQuantity();
}
```

When we need to instantiate this MatrixComponent we just write

```
<app-matrix></app-matrix>
```

in the HTML template of the parent class. This is because there will be a service like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class MatrixService {
  private columnsQuantity: number;
  private rowsQuantity:number;
  constructor(private service:SessionInfoService) {
        this.columnsQuantity = getColumnsQuantityFromDataBaseOrConstantClass();
        this.rowsQuantity = getRowsQuantityFromDataBaseOrConstantClass();
 }
  getColumnsQuantity() {
      return this.columnsQuantity;
  }
  getRowsQuantity() {
    return this.rowsQuantity;
  }
}
```

The service and the dependency injection makes sense because there is a way to get the persistent data from a database or constant values that the injectable service can access.

In the code above, the rowsQuantity and the ColumnsQuantity are persistent or constant.

But then, couldn't this injectable service be posible if the rowsQuantity and the columnsQuantity where not persistent or constant and would we always then have to use the @input decorator in the MatrixComponent?

In that case, instead of using a service in the constructor we would have to use the @input decorator like this:

```
export class MatrixComponent implements OnInit {
      @input() columnsQuantity:number;
      @input() rowsQuantity:number;
      constructor() { 

      }
    }
    ngOnInit() {


    }
```

When we need to instantiate this MatrixComponent we would have to pass the parameters

```
<app-matrix [columnsQuantity]="whateverColumnsValueHasBeenJustGottenAndIsNotPossibleToInject" [rowsQuantity] = "whateverRowssValueHasBeenJustGottenAndIsNotPossibleToInject"></app-matrix>
```

Is this always true or should I try to use dependency injection even with non persistent or constant data? In the case that I should, how can I do it?

Comment: *couldn't this injectable service be posible if the rowsQuantity and the columnsQuantity where not persistent or constant* - but they are. It's unclear what you're asking because the code doesn't reflect the problem. If the question is more like *Should I get service.getColumnsQuantity() value in parent component and pass it via input to child component, or get it in child component directly*, then the answer is 'It always depends on the case'.

Comment: @estus. What I really want to know is what would there happen if they  were not persistent or constant. You might not need a code; every time you set a variable or an object value, it is not persistent in the beginning and sometimes it never gets persistent. Thats basic programming. Being that the case, if you say, 'it always depend on the case', I would like to get an example of a case in which you can represent an injectable service which get its values from a non persistent and not constant data, if there is such a thing.

Comment: It solely depends on how you use your service. How often and on what condition the requests to DB should be performed. Should they be cached or not. Obviously, `service.getColumnsQuantity()` should be called at some point in order to get data. Considering that you know how to do this with DI, please, provide an example of how you use the service *with DI and no @Input*, then the question can be answered. If you don't know how to do this, I'd suggest to start with that.